# Defining multiple derived classes at compile time

Tags: c++, abstract-class

I am looking to save time, and avoid writing duplicate code when adding a new type.

What I currently have is along the following:

```
class BaseClass {
    std::string m_name;
public:
    BaseClass(const std::string name) : m_name(name) {};
    std::string getName(void) { return m_name; }
    virtual std::string toString(void) = 0;
};

class DerivedInt8 : public BaseClass {
    uint8_t m_value;
public:
    DerivedInt8(const uint8_t value, const std::string name) : BaseClass(name), m_value(value) {}

    virtual std::string toString(void) {
        std::ostringstream os;
        os << getName() << ": " << m_value;
        return os.str();
    }
};

class DerivedInt16 : public BaseClass {
    uint16_t m_value;
public:
    DerivedInt16(const uint16_t value, const std::string name) : BaseClass(name), m_value(value) {}

    virtual std::string toString(void) {
        std::ostringstream os;
        os << getName() << ": " << m_value;
        return os.str();
    }
};
```

I also have a derived class for uint32_t, uint64_t, and a few other custom classes. Is there a clean way in C++ I can define a new type without having to duplicate the code for each new type I decide to add in the future? In C I would have used some form of X-Macros to define everything I need at compile time; is there a mirror in C++ I can use?

Comment: just use templates

Comment: Any reason you cant use std::to_string()?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
template <typename T>
class Generic : public BaseClass {
    T m_value;
public:
    Generic(T value, const std::string& name)
    : BaseClass(name), m_value(value) {}

    std::string toString(void) const override {
        std::ostringstream os;
        os << getName() << ": " << m_value;
        return os.str();
    }
};
using DerivedInt8 = Generic<uint8_t>;
using DerivedInt16 = Generic<uint16_t>;
```

This is super basic, and should be covered in the introductory text you should *definitely* read.

You're also passing const parameters by value, which is largely pointless (I assumed you meant `const std::string&`), have methods which ought to be const-qualified (both `getName` and `toString`), and don't use `override` when implementing virtual functions.